# Add images to signature in Mail

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-mail

I am able to add a signature to each of my accounts, but since I want to use mail for my work email.  I need to add 2 images to my signature.  Ctrl + G doesn't seem to do anything in there.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same issues/desire and did manage to achieve a satisfactory result for my work email by using the 'use HTML signature' option in the settings dialogue.

I have included my signature 'code' below that I used (personal details redacted) in case it is helpful.

One important point is that you will need to find a version of the image file hosted online that you want to use for your email. If your company uses Gmail for corporate email this is easy, as it will be (most likely) hosted somewhere on the public google 'drive' for your company, but if your company doesn't have a publicly accessible space on your server where the image is located you could always host it yourself somewhere and link to that file in your signature code.

It ends up looking like the image attached here.

[image]

```
<div style="white-space:normal">
<p style="margin-bottom:0cm;border:none;padding:0cm;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:1pt">
<span style="display:inline-block;border:none;padding:0cm"><font face="Oswald"><font style="font-size:11pt" size="3"><b><font color="#009078">Jos Henson</font></b></font></font></span></p>
<p style="border:none;padding:0cm;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:1pt;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:10px">
<span style="display:inline-block;border:none;padding:0cm"><font face="Oswald"><font style="font-size:8pt" size="1"><b><font color="#a0a0a0">International Investor Relations<br></font></b></font></font></span></p>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="558" height="93">
<colgroup>
<col width="109*"> 
<col width="147*">
</colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr valign="top">
<td style="border:none;padding:0cm" width="43%">
<p style="border:none;padding:0cm"><span style="display:inline-block;border:none;padding:0cm;margin-top:0px"><font face="Oswald"><font style="font-size:8pt" size="1">
<font color="#b2b2b2"><a style="text-decoration:none;color:#b2b2b2" href="tel:+421%20919%20225%20628" value="+421919225628" target="_blank">+421 919 225 628</a> 
<br>
</font></font></font>
<font color="#b2b2b2"><span style="text-decoration:none;"><font face="Oswald"><font style="font-size:8pt" size="1"><a style="text-decoration:none;color:#b2b2b2" href="mailto:j.henson@zltymelon.sk" target="_blank">j.henson@zltymelon.sk</a></font></font></span></font>
<font face="Oswald"><font style="font-size:8pt" size="1"><font color="#b2b2b2"><br>
</font></font></font>
<span style="text-decoration:none;"><font face="Oswald"><font style="font-size:8pt" size="1"><font color="#b2b2b2"><a style="text-decoration:none;color:#b2b2b2" href="http://www.zltymelon.com" target="_blank" >www.zltymelon.com</a></font></font></font></span></span><span><br></span></p>
<p style="border:none;padding:0cm;font-weight:normal"><font face="Oswald"><font style="font-size:8pt" size="1"><font color="#b2b2b2"><span style="display:inline-block;border:none;padding:0cm"><br></span></font></font></font></p>
<p style="border:none;padding:0cm"><span><img src="~~https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/ViudISRIsqWTahqLqSj_P9WRDiw6JONkQbL75CvFXE5JB-pjnr_BMJhsrJHqQ5WTyNzR8c-FT1WRGh8Cw2vBiKNVLnFQYfsqmKWRsIQZzAnJ71CLXgabktfroe50Fel6_cQKhlNodq8WOkW34WtU=s0-d-e1-ft#https://docs.google.com/a/zltymelon.sk/uc?id=0BztgNOLiYfWBampNNFF0bHlSUDg&amp;export=download~~"></span></p>
<p style="border:none;padding:0cm"><span><br></span></p>    
<td style="border:none;padding:0cm" width="57%">
<p style="border:none;padding:0cm;margin-top:0px"><font face="Oswald"><font style="font-size:8pt" size="1"><font color="#b2b2b2"><span style="display:inline-block;border:none;padding:0cm">&nbsp;</span></font></font></font><span></span>
<span style="display:inline-block;border:none;padding:0cm;"><font face="Oswald"><font style="font-size:8pt" size="1"><font color="#b2b2b2">iService a.s.<br>
</font></font></font>
<font color="#b2b2b2"><span style="text-decoration:none;"><font face="Oswald"><font style="font-size:8pt" size="1">Strakova 1,&nbsp; Bratislava&nbsp; 811 01,&nbsp; Slovakia</font></font></span></font>
<font face="Oswald"><font style="font-size:8pt" size="1"><font color="#b2b2b2"><br>
</font></font></font><span style="text-decoration:none;"><font face="Oswald"><font style="font-size:8pt" size="1"><font color="#b2b2b2"><a style="text-decoration:none;color:#b2b2b2" href="tel:+421%202/544%20100%2084" value="+421254410084" target="_blank">+421 2 544 100 84</a></font></font></font></span></span></p>
<p style="border:none;padding:0cm;font-weight:normal"><font face="Oswald"><font style="font-size:8pt" size="1"><font color="#b2b2b2"><span style="display:inline-block;border:none;padding:0cm"><br></span></font></font></font></p>
<p style="border:none;padding:0cm"><span><br></span></p>                            

</td>   

</td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```